# pthreads memcpy and realloc in C

Tags: c, pthreads, memcpy

I am trying my luck with pthreads for a problem -
I have two questions about that and will add some excerpts from the code:

1. I have a struct, which contains an input array and one as output (or result) array. Where do I have to allocate the memory for this result, within the main-function or within the thread-function?
2. These results shall be merged into one big result array using realloc and memcpy. I think I am using memcpy and realloc not correctly in this case, or do I?

thread-Function:

```
struct thread_input {
    unsigned char *buf;
    unsigned char *result;
    int start;
    int end;
    int tid;

};



void* thread_function(void* arg){
    struct thread_input *param = (struct thread_input*)arg;

    param->result = (unsigned char*)malloc((1+(param->end-param->start))*sizeof(unsigned char));

    for(int i = param->start; i <= param->end; i++){

        param->result[i] = some_function(param->buf[i]);
        printf("%d %d\n", param->tid, param->result[i]);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

So the some_function is working with every unsigned char and returns it to the param->result array.

This shall be merged here (where n_elemts is the number calculated in every thread):

```
unsigned char* arr1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(n_elements*sizeof(unsigned char));

    for (int t = 0; t < n_threads; t++){
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);

        memcpy(arr1, thread_args[t].result, n_elements);
        if(t<n_threads-1){
            arr1 = (unsigned char*)realloc(arr1, (t+1)*n_elements*sizeof(unsigned char));
        }
    }

    print_function(arr1, fileSize);
```

The problem given by the compiler is located at the realloc and called "invalid read of size 1", I suppose it is due to a wrong file_size, or array length, after the realloc. Plus the allocation of the param->result that I could not figure out completely.

Thanks for lookin at these excerpts and for any comment! Hope this question was asked in concise enough way, if not bombard me with critic.

Comment: Both `realloc` and `memcpy` are fine. You may be misusing them, but they're OK for multi-threaded programming in general.

Comment: haha okay, yes that is what a friend I consulted could tell me, so I agree about the misuse, but I honestly have no clue where right now. My realloc is not causing an overwriting of arr1?
If I start with a filesize of 8 and use 2 threads with both 4 elements I end up with an error, while 1 thread (8 elements) is running fine.

Edit: I can add, that the param->results print out the correct number within the thread-function, so the error must happen somewhere during the transfer from thread to join.

Comment: `param->result[i]` ==> `param->result[i - param->start]`.

Comment: Are you sure about memcpy(arr1, thread_args[t].result, n_elements); ? Each loop overwrite same data in arr1...

Comment: Why don't you do `malloc(n_elements * n_threads);`? You know the numbers before.

Comment: @LPs: no exactly that was my suspicion, what I thought when asking point 2 (should have added that above) ...

Comment: If you know the number of threads before the join loop you can pre-allocate the whole space before and into loop just `memcpy(&arr1[t*n_elements], thread_args[t].result, n_elements);`

Comment: Are you sure result record size is 1 byte only

Comment: honestly, that was amazing! I think I got it to run at least for my test case! I always overwrote the first four/eight elements in memcpy (not changing the address right?). I had the allocation with malloc before, but somehow thought I must to use realloc when using memcpy ...

@mch: what is the reasoning behind your suggestion? I just tried to wrote it on paper but I somehow must have made a mistake there as well

Comment: Do you want an explanation about my first or my second comment?

Comment: @mch: I wanted one for the first one, but I see it now, I think:
Since I always want, for the n=2 case, have the elements 0 to 3, I have to subtract the start-index right?